# field map string values in one field to domain field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, domains

Is there a method in ArcGIS 10.3.1 to calculate coded value domains in a domain field based on a string field source? Please see image.

The solution appears to be to use the CalculateField GP in ArcCatalog as opposed to calculating within an ArcMap session. While this method works, is it possible to display the coded values in the field **without** the descriptions?

[image: Image displays screen capture of table showing source string field and target domain field, along with domain coded values.]

Comment: I think you'll need to use [Domain To Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/domain-to-table.htm) followed by a join and calc.

Comment: field calculate the subparcel into lu field and it will pick up the Code and display the Description?

Comment: @GISI - That worked - thanks! Now: Can we do that without displaying the domain description?

Comment: If you have a new question, now while there are no answers to the original would be a good time, to overhaul it with what you have now done, and where you are now stuck.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking here - it seems like you want to display the coded values in the `lu` field, but isn't that what you already have in your `subParcel` field?

Comment: The subparcel field is simply being used to stage string values that represent coded domain values that must be calculated into the "lu" domain field. The field calculator GP worked to calculate "lu" based on the string values in subparcel but ideally I could do so without the result including the domain descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you may be looking for is the Esri Technical Article on [HowTo:  Display coded value domains and subtype codes instead of descriptions](http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/43215):

> By default, ArcMap displays the coded value domain and subtype
>   descriptions in the attribute table. The instructions provided ...
>   describe how to display the coded value domain and subtype codes
>   instead of their descriptions.

The trick is to go to Customize | ArcMap Options > Tables tab and uncheck **Display coded value domain and subtype descriptions**